# How do messages get consumed in Kafka when there are more partitions than consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka

This is a very basic question about Kafka and how messages are consumed but I was not able to find any answer on this point, unfortunately :'(.

Let's say I want to over partition a bit, so I would get 10 times more partitions than consumers. Over partition is required as I want to be able to scale (process more messages in parallel in the future).

1 topic divided in 1000 partitions consumed by 100 consumers =-> each consumer get assigned 10 partitions.

**My questions are :**

- How messages are consumed for each consumer : is it done in a round-robin fashion ? If not, how is the distribution done ?
- Is there any guarantee that the messages are going to be consumed evenly by the consumer between the 10 partitions they are assigned to ? Is there a risk that some partitions never get consumed ?

I was not able to find any answer on this point. And sorry if it's a duplicate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The consumption of messages is done in a round robin way between the set of partitions assigned to a Consumer.
- No, there is no guarantee that the messages are going to be consumed evenly between partitions. In the documentation for KIP-41 you can see an [explanation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records#KIP-41:KafkaConsumerMaxRecords-EnsuringFairConsumption) on how this will work when you can specify the number of messages

Comment: I have some troubles to understand if it is implemented yet or not. Do you know about this ?

Comment: KIP-41 will be available in the next version 0.9.1 but the rest of the explanation that I gave you is still valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your research work !